# How do I choose Aspect Ratio for OpenCV Cascade Training?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am about to do training in OpenCV for a numberplate recognition system.
I am running Python 2.7 / Ubuntu 12.04 / OpenCV (python bindings)
Installed through sudo apt-get install python-opencv

I have marked all the images as follows:

```
images/img000.jpg 1 112 132 203 54
images/img000.jpg 1 112 132 217 47

Note : 203 x 54 has aspect ratio 3.73
Note : 217 x 47 has aspect ratio 4.56
```

or in the general sense:

```
image_dir/filename [#num of bounding rects] x y width height
```

When I run opencv_createsamples with the following parameters, I have no problems and the program runs fine to create the samples.vec file:
(see [Tutorial: OpenCV Haar Training](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#e5c54f60))

```
opencv_createsamples -info samples.dat -vec samples.vec -w 144 -h 50
```

**Now in my examples given, we note that two of the numberplates are similar in size, but do not have the same aspect ratio.**

So now if I have objects of aspect ratio of between 3.5 and 4.5 , **how do I select -w and -h values for sample creation?**

- I could use the minimum or maximum aspect ratio?
- I could use the average aspect ratio?

I am worried that if I base these values on the shorter plates, some of the longer plates will get cut off (horizontally), and if I base these values on the longer plates, some of the height of the shorter plates may get cut off (vertically). Perhaps my thinking is even wrong?

Note: I am aware that the -w and -h should be smaller than the smallest plate that you want to be recognised.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't want the aspect ratio of your objects to vary much.  If it does, the objects with the "wrong" aspect ratio may not be detected at all, and you may have to train several detectors instead of one.  But if the variance is not too great, I would use the median aspect ratio.  In fact, the `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for Matlab will do that for you.